# How could i split a column array from df, into a new one df?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with some columns, one of them is a an array of hours, and I want to split this array of hours into new columns per index.

For example:

If my array is of 24 hours, I have to create a new df with 24 new columns one by hour
[image]

Comment: i  have to do it for the seven days (monday, tuesday, wednesday, ....) and also the df has about 30 columns withouth hours per day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with spark inbuilt functions **`posexplode,concat,groupBy,pivot`** for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
#test dataframe
val df=Seq(("rome","escuels",Seq(0,1,2,3,4,5)), 
           ("madrid","farmacia",Seq(0,1,2,3,4,5)))
       .toDF("city","institute","monday_hours")

df.selectExpr("posexplode(monday_hours) as (p,c)","*") //pos explode gives position and col value
  .selectExpr("concat('monday_',p) as m ","c","city","institute")
  .groupBy("city","institute")
  .pivot("m") //pivot on m column
  .agg(first("c")) //get the first value from c column value.
  .show()
```

***Result:***

```
+------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  city|institute|monday_0|monday_1|monday_2|monday_3|monday_4|monday_5|
+------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|madrid| farmacia|       0|       1|       2|       3|       4|       5|
|  rome|  escuels|       0|       1|       2|       3|       4|       5|
+------+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```